# an application of bounded convergence theorem

Tags: probability-theory

I have read the following statement:

$P\{Y_{t}\neq Y_{t+u} \mid Y_0=i\}=\sum_{j\in E}P_t (i,j)[1-P_u(j,j)]$,
where $E$ is a countable set.

As $u\downarrow 0$ we have $1-P_u(j,j)\to 0$. This implies that $P\{Y_{t-u}\neq Y_t \mid Y_0=i\}\to 0$ by the bounded convergence theorem.

What I do not understand is that why we need the bounded convergence theorem for this result to hold?

Comment: Well, what alternative reasoning do you suggest? How would you prove that the expression converges to $0$?

Comment: I am sorry SAZ. I guess I have asked the question in a confusing way. What   I want to understand is that in which part of the proof, the bounded convergence theorem is used. While taking the limit inside the sum? Moreover, the bounded convergence theorem is for sequences. However, here u seems to be continuous. Thank you very much for your answer...

Answer (score 0):

You'd like to say that $\lim_{u \downarrow 0} \sum_{j \in E} P_t(i, j) [1 - P_u(j, j)] = \sum_{j \in E} \lim_{u \downarrow 0} P_t(i, j) [1 - P_u(j, j)]$, but this operation of interchanging limits and sums is not always valid.  In this situation it's justified by the monotone convergence theorem since $1 - P_u(j, j)$ is decreasing in $u$ and the sum is finite.

Comment: The monotonicity is not guaranteed.

Comment: Now I got it. Since monotonicity is nor guaranteed, we need bounded convergence theorem. Inside the sum is uniformly bounded since they are probabilities.

Comment: If $\sum_{j \in E} P_t(i, j) < \infty$ then dominated convergence should work as well.